# Prove $\text{min } \mathbb{E}[Y-g(X)] = \mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|X])^2]$ where the min is with respect to g(X)

Tags: optimization, random-variables, conditional-expectation, expected-value

As my title states, I'm trying to prove
$$
\text{min } \mathbb{E}[Y-g(X)] = \mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|X])^2]
$$
where the min is with respect to g(X) and I think I am very close to the answer. So far I have expanded $\mathbb{E}[Y-g(X)]$ to
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big[(Y-g(X))^2\Big]=\mathbb{E}\Big[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|X])^2\Big]+2\mathbb{E}\Big[Y\mathbb{E}[Y|X]-Yg(X)-\mathbb{E}[Y|X]^2+\mathbb{E}[Y|X]g(X)\Big]+\mathbb{E}\Big[(\mathbb{E}[Y|X]-g(X))^2\Big]
$$
I see here that if I set $g(X)=\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$, all the terms will go to $0$ except for $\mathbb{E}\Big[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|X])^2\Big]$, making
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big[(Y-g(X))^2\Big]=\mathbb{E}\Big[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|X])^2\Big]
$$
which appears to be what the question asks for. My question is if this would really prove what I am trying to prove or not? If not, I am unsure of how I would show what these expected values would be to make things more explicit.

Comment: You have to show that $E(Y-g(X))^{2}) \leq E(Y-E(Y|X))^{2}$ for every measurable function $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $. Some knowedege of projections on a Hilbert space would be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no knowledge of projections on a Hilbert space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditioning on $X$ gives:

$$\mathbb{E}[(Y-g(X))^2] = \mathbb{E}\bigg[\mathbb{E}\bigg[(Y-g(X))^2 \vert X \bigg]\bigg].$$

Note that this is equivalent to factoring the joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and splitting up the integral.

Denote $h(x) = \mathbb{E}\bigg[(Y-g(X))^2 \vert X = x\bigg]$ (or the inner integral)

We have: $h(x) \geq  \mathbb{E}\bigg[(Y-\mathbb{E}(Y\vert X))^2 \vert X = x\bigg]$

Therefore,

$$\mathbb{E}[(Y-g(X))^2] \geq \mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}(Y\vert X))^2],$$

where the equality holds for $g(X) = \mathbb{E}(Y\vert X).$

Comment: Thank you for the help. Not sure I understand the leap from the conditioning to the >= part

Comment: If you want to minimize $\mathbb{E}[(X-c)^2],$ where $c$ is a constant, you can easily show that the minimum is attained for $c = \mathbb{E}[X]$, hence the inequality above

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification and apologies if it was a silly question!